# React Native fetch throws undefined is not a function evaluating ((0,_reactNative.fetch)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Am new to react native, am trying to access remote url throws this error. "undefined is not a function evaluating ((0,_reactNative.fetch)". Not sure what am doing wrong; Please help. 
Am using the latest version of react native 0.40

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
  View, 
  Text,
  Button,
  fetch,
  NativeModules,
  NativeEventEmitter 
} from "react-native";

export default class VideoScreen extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
       this.video();
    }
    video(){
       fetch('http://localhost:4200/token').then(function(res) {
         console.log(res.json());

        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Obviously, `fetch` is not a function. Just use polyfill.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment helped me point out my stupidity. " Wasn't supposed to be importing fetch from react-native"

Comment: Ha, that's right, didn't notice this imports. Of course, fetch is supposed to be native function for platform, you don't import it, unless you use fetch polyfill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

removing fetch from the import statement makes it work.

```
import { 
  View, 
  Text,
  Button,
  NativeModules,
  NativeEventEmitter 
} from "react-native";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is resolved by adding this code to App.js :

```
if(typeof global.self === "undefined")
{
    global.self = global;
}
```